# Suddenly I got this FAILURE when i run Flutter app on android studio "Could not initialize class org.codehaus"

Tags: android-studio, flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I'm using:
Android studio : 4.1.1
JDK version: 15.0.1
Gradle version:gradle-6.7
Flutter version: 1.22.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your gradle version from 6.7 to 6.4, It worked for me.

Also run Flutter Doctor and check if certificates are accepted ( Sometimes we have to reaccept it again).

Comment: I used gradle-5.6.2-all.zip  and works as well for me